# How does httprouterhttp.HandlerFunc() works?

Tags: go

I am learning Go and at the moment trying to understand what and how actually [julienschmidt's httprouterhttp](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter) router works. Especially how the router.HandlerFunc() works.

**Go's http package:**

- `http.Handler`: Handler is an Interface. Any type which has the same method signature i.e., ServeHTTP(w,r) implements a Handler.
- `http.Handle`: http.Handle is a function which has two parameters. 1) String to match request path, 2)Handler, to call its ServeHTTP() method.
- `http.HandlerFunc`: A custom function type with function signature (ResponseWriter, *Request) and its own ServeHTTP(w,r) method, which satisfies as a http.Handler interface.

Now if I need to use a function eg. Bar(ResponseWriter, *Request) which satisfies to be a HandlerFunc, inside http.Handle, I type caste/covert the function to http.HandlerFunc and then use it inside the http.Handle. Like so:

```
func Bar(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("My bar func response"))
}
...
mf := http.HandlerFunc(Bar)
http.Handle("/path", mf)
```

- Looking at the [http.HandleFunc source code](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18.3:src/net/http/server.go;l=2511), this is how http.HandleFunc() works. It expects a function which as the signature of (w ResponseWriter, r *Request) and type caste the function.

Like so:

```
func (mux *ServeMux) HandleFunc(pattern string, handler func(ResponseWriter, *Request)) {
    if handler == nil {
        panic("http: nil handler")
    }
    mux.Handle(pattern, HandlerFunc(handler))
}
```

**julienschmidt's httprouterhttp**

Looking at the [source code of router.HandlerFunc()](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter/blob/v1.3.0/router.go#L282)

```
func (r *Router) HandlerFunc(method, path string, handler http.HandlerFunc) {
    r.Handler(method, path, handler)
}
```

- Instead of expecting a function with appropriate signature (ResponseWriter, *Request) like the http.HandleFunc(), it expects a http.HandlerFunc.
- Also without type casting/converting the function to a HandlerFunc type, it just pass the function to another function router.Handler(method, path string, handler http.Handler), which again expects a Handler.

So I can execute this code without any problem:

```
router.HandlerFunc(http.MethodPost, "/path", Bar) // Bar is not type casted/converted to a HandlerFunc
```

I can understand type casting the Bar to a HandlerFunc and then pass it to router.HandlerFunc().

Could you please clear some of my doubts:

1. How does without type casting the Bar() to a HandlerFunc satisfies as a HandlerFunc type to the router.HandlerFunc()?
2. If the router.Handler() expects a http.Handler type, how come Bar() without type casting to the http.HandlerFunc satisfies a a Handler to the router.Handler()?
3. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. *"How does without type casting the Bar() to a HandlerFunc satisfies as a HandlerFunc type to the router.HandlerFunc()?"*

The expression

```golang
router.HandlerFunc(http.MethodPost, "/path", Bar)
```

complies with the rules of [Assignability](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignability):

> `V` and `T` have **identical underlying types** and at least one of `V` or `T` is **not a named** type.

The `Bar` function's type and the `http.HandlerFunc` type have **identical underlying types**, and `Bar`'s type is **not named**. Because of that you can pass (assign) `Bar` as the `handler` argument to `httprouter.Router.HandlerFunc` without an *explicit conversion*.

---

2. *"If the router.Handler() expects a http.Handler type, how come Bar() without type casting to the http.HandlerFunc satisfies a a Handler to the router.Handler()?"*

In the following method definition

```golang
func (r *Router) HandlerFunc(method, path string, handler http.HandlerFunc) {
    r.Handler(method, path, handler)
}
```

there is *no* `Bar`, there's only the `handler` argument whose type *is* `http.HandlerFunc` and that type *does* implement the `http.Handler` interface. So the statement `r.Handler(method, path, handler)` is perfectly legitimate.

---

3. *"What am I missing?"*

See above.

Comment: I am still somewhat struggling to understand the concept here. Could you please help me out with your points: 1) Am I correct to assume that if they (Bar() and http.HandlerFunc) have the same underlying types and signature, it means even if Bar() doesn't have the ServeHTTP method it can be assignable as a http.Handlerfunc? 2) Here I meant the router.HandlerFunc() expects a method, string and a http.HandlerFunc. Since as your point 1) the function Bar() will have explicit conversion, there is no need for Bar() to be type casted to a HandlerFunc type to be passed as a http.Handler.

Comment: 1. Yes, that's exactly what that means. https://go.dev/play/p/2Vs3JkVzemr

Comment: Okay! Also thank you for the example on go playground. Could you also please correct me on the second point of yours. Since now that Bar is assinged (implictly converted) as a HandlerFunc, it doesn't require to be explicitly converted to a HandlerFunc and can be passed as a Handler on router.Handler(method, string, http.Handler)?

Comment: @MswTm Why would it need to be explicitly converted? In point 1. we've already established that you can pass `Bar` as `handler` to the `Router.HandlerFunc` method without explicit conversion, right? So the second point is pointless.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense now. I think now I have a much better understanding. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Look at definition of HandlerFunc

```
type HandlerFunc func(ResponseWriter, *Request)
```

And the signature of your function

```
(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)
```

You don't need conversion here.

Comment: HandlerFunc also has a ServeHTTP method, but Bar doesn't. Is ServeHTTP() method not required to be assignable as a http.HandlerFunc, as it is just a medhod and not a type defination?